# how to calculate checksum as per AIS 140 standard

Tags: ais

I want to send a message to the server as per the `AIS 140` standard. Please explain how to calculate the `checksum`. Find below the sample message format.

```
$Header,iTriangle,KA01I2000,861693034634154,1_37T02B0164MAIS,AIS140,12.976545,N,77.5497 59,E*50
```

Answer (score 0):

As per **AIS140 Standard** Checksum is calculated by performing *xor* to all bytes received from packet.

Note: You have to remove ***'$'***.

Caution: Use data from device to verify this code (Example provided from doc doesnt have valid checksum)

This Javascript code will help your job done.

```
function checksum(packet) {
  const charArray = packet.split('');
  let xor = 0;
  const n = charArray.length;
  for (let i = 1; i < n - 3; i++) {
    xor = xor ^ charArray[i].charCodeAt(0);
  }
  const cs = parseInt("0x" + charArray[n - 2] + charArray[n - 1]);
  return xor === cs;
}
checksum('$Header,iTriangle,KA01I2000,861693034634154,1_37T02B0164MAIS,AIS140,12.976545,N,77.549759,E*50')
```